# the string position in code doesn't correspond with the position in the output pdf

Tags: xetex, positioning, pdf, strings

I have a code like below, and I want to insert the string "22222222222222222222222222"
at the place above `\date{today}`
as is in the code, **but** it appears on the first page and `today` is on the second page. How can I make them to be on the same page (and above `today`) ?

**EDIT**
Also when I put 2 times this `\date{today}` it appears only once, why ?

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper, % Page size
    fontsize=10pt, % Base font size
    twoside=true, % Use different layouts for even and odd pages (in ipt documentation for an in-depth explanation)
]{kaobook}


\let\providelength\relax
\usepackage{dialogue}


% Choose the language
\ifxetexorluatex
    \let\providelength\relax
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
\else
    \let\providelength\relax
    \usepackage[english]{babel} % Load characters and hyphenation
\fi
\usepackage[english=british]{csquotes}  % English quotes



%\documentclass{book}



\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

 \usepackage[natbib=true]{biblatex}

 % include the chapter number
 \setlist[enumerate]{label=\thechapter.\arabic{*},resume}

 % restart the enumerate list every chapter
 \preto\chapter{%
   \restartlist{enumerate}%
}














% Load packages for testing
\usepackage{blindtext}
 
\usepackage{kaobiblio}
\addbibresource{main.bib} % Bibliography file




% Load mathematical packages for theorems and related environments
\usepackage[framed=true]{kaotheorems}

% Load the package for hyperreferences
\usepackage{kaorefs}

\graphicspath{{examples/documentation/images/}{images/}} % Paths in which to look for images

\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc] % Make LaTeX produce the files required to compile the index

\makeglossaries % Make LaTeX produce the files required to compile the glossary
\input{glossary.tex} % Include the glossary definitions

\makenomenclature % Make LaTeX produce the files required to compile the nomenclature

 
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}

 
\titlehead{The \texttt{proper} class}
\subject{}

\title[Example and documentation of the {\normalfont\texttt{kaobook}} class]{On the {\normalfont\texttt{Second  }} and  }
\subtitle{Provability }

\author[Y]{J K\thanks{A \LaTeX\ lover}}

\date{\today}
22222222222222222222222222
\date{\today}


999999999999999
\publishers{ submitted in  }

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\frontmatter % Denotes the start of the pre-document content, uses roman numerals

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OPENING PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 
\makeatletter
\uppertitleback{\@titlehead} % Header
 
 
\maketitle

 
\index{preface}




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS & LIST OF FIGURES/TABLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup % Local scope for the following commands

% Define the style for the TOC, LOF, and LOT
%\setstretch{1} % Uncomment to modify line spacing in the ToC
%\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue} % Uncomment to set the colour of links in the ToC
\setlength{\textheight}{230\hscale} % Manually adjust the height of the ToC pages

% Turn on compatibility mode for the etoc package
\etocstandarddisplaystyle % "toc display" as if etoc was not loaded
\etocstandardlines % "toc lines" as if etoc was not loaded

\tableofcontents % Output the table of contents

\listoffigures % Output the list of figures

% Comment both of the following lines to have the LOF and the LOT on different pages
\let\cleardoublepage\bigskip
\let\clearpage\bigskip

\listoftables % Output the list of tables

\endgroup

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN BODY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\end{document}
```

Comment: Macros like `\date{...}` don't actually print the date, they store the information in the a macro. Your title page gets added by `\maketitle` which will use all the information previously stored in macros. If you want to create a custom title page, have a look at the `titling` package

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It is difficult to understand. Could you kindly give me an `example` in here ? I simply want to add a picture above the date: some example with my code will do.

Comment: I can't compile your code because I don't have the documentclass and your question does not say where to get it from.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Which extension do you need: `.sty`  or `.cls` ? Please see [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/kaobook) download the source section.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty hack:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper, % Page size
    fontsize=10pt, % Base font size
    twoside=true, % Use different layouts for even and odd pages (in ipt documentation for an in-depth explanation)
]{kaobook}


\let\providelength\relax
\usepackage{dialogue}


% Choose the language
\ifxetexorluatex
    \let\providelength\relax
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
\else
    \let\providelength\relax
    \usepackage[english]{babel} % Load characters and hyphenation
\fi
\usepackage[english=british]{csquotes}  % English quotes



%\documentclass{book}



\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

 \usepackage[natbib=true]{biblatex}

 % include the chapter number
 \setlist[enumerate]{label=\thechapter.\arabic{*},resume}

 % restart the enumerate list every chapter
 \preto\chapter{%
   \restartlist{enumerate}%
}














% Load packages for testing
\usepackage{blindtext}
 
\usepackage{kaobiblio}
\addbibresource{main.bib} % Bibliography file




% Load mathematical packages for theorems and related environments
\usepackage[framed=true]{kaotheorems}

% Load the package for hyperreferences
\usepackage{kaorefs}

\graphicspath{{examples/documentation/images/}{images/}} % Paths in which to look for images

\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc] % Make LaTeX produce the files required to compile the index

\makeglossaries % Make LaTeX produce the files required to compile the glossary
\input{glossary.tex} % Include the glossary definitions

\makenomenclature % Make LaTeX produce the files required to compile the nomenclature

 
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\addtokomafont{date}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}\endgraf}

\begin{document}

 
\titlehead{The \texttt{proper} class}
\subject{}

\title[Example and documentation of the {\normalfont\texttt{kaobook}} class]{On the {\normalfont\texttt{Second  }} and  }
\subtitle{Provability }

\author[Y]{J K\thanks{A \LaTeX\ lover}}

\date{\today}

\publishers{ submitted in  }

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\frontmatter % Denotes the start of the pre-document content, uses roman numerals

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OPENING PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 
\makeatletter
\uppertitleback{\@titlehead} % Header
 
 
\maketitle

 
\index{preface}




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS & LIST OF FIGURES/TABLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup % Local scope for the following commands

% Define the style for the TOC, LOF, and LOT
%\setstretch{1} % Uncomment to modify line spacing in the ToC
%\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue} % Uncomment to set the colour of links in the ToC
\setlength{\textheight}{230\hscale} % Manually adjust the height of the ToC pages

% Turn on compatibility mode for the etoc package
\etocstandarddisplaystyle % "toc display" as if etoc was not loaded
\etocstandardlines % "toc lines" as if etoc was not loaded

\tableofcontents % Output the table of contents

\listoffigures % Output the list of figures

% Comment both of the following lines to have the LOF and the LOT on different pages
\let\cleardoublepage\bigskip
\let\clearpage\bigskip

\listoftables % Output the list of tables

\endgroup

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN BODY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine. Could you kindly explain to me the essence of your hack *and* where, on the cover in the thesis,typographically, should the image be placed ? Above or below the date ? I think that definitely below my name, is that correct ? How can I change the position of the image on the cover ?

Comment: @user2925716 The hack is that under the hood your special class uses a koma script class, so I smuggled the image in with `\addtokomafont{date}{...}`. This command is normally meant to change the font of the date. Where the image should be placed is not a latex question, you should ask this somewhere else. I added it above the date, because this is what you said in your comment.